# Opening log4j Debug console in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, console, log4j

I am using the standard Eclipse with AndroidSDK. It provides some logging consoles in the bottom. Unfortunately I closed the log4j console tab.

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 0):

Window -> Show View -> Other -> LogCat